# How to convert UTF-8 encoded csv to Microsoft Excel xls by PHP?

Tags: php, excel, csv

Is there an existing PHP module to convert UTF-8 encoded `.csv` to an Excel `.xls` file? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using a library such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), which can read spreadsheets in a variety of formats (including CSV) and write to Excel .xls or .xlsx files.

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'CSV';
$inputFileName = 'inputFile.csv';
$outputFileType = 'Excel5';
$outputFileName = 'outputFile.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $outputFileType);
$objWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in PHP
http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/01/12/convert-csv-to-xls-excel-in-php/